# How to share /var/www/sites directory on network in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have one directory

```
/var/www/sites
```

I want to share it on network so that all users can copy an paste files there.
How can i do it?

Comment: A question like this really needs to include more information. What operating system is run on the connecting clients? Are these computers connecting from a local or a remote network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the Operating System of the connecting clients I would go with either Samba (Windows, etc) or NFS (Linux, etc). For more info, see these Ubuntu specific instructions...

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/network-file-system.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP can make it pretty easy to do that for Windows users, and it uses existing SSH connection - you don't need extra services, just make sure that the users have access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use samba or NFS. You can also use FTP or better SFTP.